# What tense is denoted by this construction?

Tags: tense, time, participles

In a technical document, which I have been reading, I am faced with the following sentence:

> A name having namespace scope that has not been given internal linkage
>   above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace [...]

I don't understand what exact time-construction is denoted by the *has not been given* word-combination. I had been thinking that this construction denotes the *present perfect continuous*, but it is not true, because the verb is used in the *past participle* form instead of *present participle* form.

Comment: It's in the passive voice. *"[namespace scope] has not been given [internal linkage above]"* This is plainly in the present perfect tense. Compare the passive voice in these different tenses. Simple Present: X is (not) given Y. Simple Past: X was (not) given Y. Present Perfect: X has (not) been given Y.

Comment: Indeed, I've understood you. Thanks. The misunderstanding was in using of to be in the `past participate` form.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Post the answer and claim your billiken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *A name having namespace scope that **has not been given** internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace [...]*

As you understand correctly, *has not been given* is not in the present perfect continuous. But what is it? Its tense is the present perfect tense, and it is in the "passive voice".

How can we know that a given sentence (or clause) is in the passive voice? The trick is to notice **the auxiliary *be* + past participle**.

A few examples might help. Compare the passive voice in these different tenses.

> Simple Present: *X is (not) given Y.*
>   Simple Past: *X was (not) given Y.*
>   Present Perfect: *X has (not) been given Y.*

As you can see, your example, *"... [namespace scope that] **has not been given** [internal linkage above]"* fits the passive voice in the present perfect pattern.